# Does pytest 3.x have anything significant over 2.x?

Tags: python, anaconda, pytest, pypi, conda

I've learned that Python Anaconda's `conda` program is much better than `pip` at managing packages and environments --- it even has dependency conflict management, which `pip` does not have.

The problem is that `conda` uses the Continuum repository instead of PyPI, and many things (e.g. `cx_Oracle`) are so out of date there! One of the biggest is `pytest`, which on Continuum only goes to version 2.9.2 at the moment, while PyPI is already at `pytest` version 3.0.2.

So does the version 3.x line of `pytest` have significant features over the 2.x line? Or must I abandon `conda` and its superior package management and switch back to `pip` so I can get the latest packages? (I shouldn't have to make this decision... but such is the Python ecosystem.)

P.S. I know I can hunt around and specify a different Continuum channel and perhaps pick up a newer `pytest` using `conda`, but I'm getting tired of everything being out of date and having to specify a list of channels every time I create an environment. P.P.S. Yes I know there is probably a requirements list format that includes the channels, but that misses the point. Plus we want the requirements list to interoperate with those using `pip`.

Comment: I would suggest reading this. https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3 but judging by your rep you prob already have.

Comment: @thesonyman101  Why should he read a comparison of python2 and python3 to decide on a version of the 3rd-party pytest?

Comment: Why not even if it has nothing to do with the question it's still a good read. Not like I posted an answer saying read this.

Comment: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html

Comment: Why not add the channels to your conda config? `conda config --add channels conda-forge`. Of course, then you get everything from conda-forge, but they tend to be pretty up-to-date

Comment: Did you read my P.S.'s?

Answer (score 1):

Although I've had good experience with `conda` in the past, I would suggest taking a look at [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).

`pyenv` is written purely in bash and allows you to easily handle the installation and management of different python interpreters and virtual environments.

In my opinion, it has the best features of tools like conda, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper and more, while avoiding any dependency besides bash and playing well with the existing Python ecosystem rather than another package repository like conda.

Comment: How does it detect and handle dependency conflicts? How well does it work on Windows (not WSL)?